# rails render collection nests partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb, partials

I'm trying to render out a collection with rails. 
This looks a straightforward action, when following the rails guides' [section on the topic](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-collections).

> Partials are very useful in rendering collections. When you pass a collection to a partial via the `:collection` option, the partial will be inserted once for each member in the collection:

So following this advice I state

```
<%= render partial: "comments/comment", collection: @post.comments %>
```

and in the partial `views/comments/_comment.html.erb` all I have the following

```
<div="comment_wrapper">
<p class="comment_name"><%= comment.name %></p>
<p class="comment_date"><%= comment.created_at %></p>
<p class="comment_body"><%= comment.body %></p>
</div>
```

Now somehow all of these partials get nested into eachother.
So let's say I have 2 comments then it would be rendered like this

```
<div="comment_wrapper">
<p class="comment_name"><%= comment.name %></p>
<p class="comment_date"><%= comment.created_at %></p>
<p class="comment_body"><%= comment.body %></p>
     <div="comment_wrapper">
     <p class="comment_name"><%= comment.name %></p>
     <p class="comment_date"><%= comment.created_at %></p>
     <p class="comment_body"><%= comment.body %></p>
     </div>
</div>
```

Does anybody understand why this is happening? And how to prevent it? Thanks in advance

Comment: <div="comment_wrapper">

should probably be

    <div class="comment_wrapper">

Comment: Dios mio, and I was sitting here with my hands in my hair, not understanding this weird behaviour. Thank you for helping me out with this silly silly mistake. I overlooked it over and over...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### In fact, they don't.

It's just your browser trying to make sense of the invalid HTML to build a displayable DOM.

```
<div="comment_wrapper">
```

This is not valid. Tags have attributes that can have values assigned to them. I guess it's about CSS (so the attribute is either `id` or `class`) and there's clearly more than one occurrence of such on the page (which leaves only `class`):

```
<div class="comment_wrapper">
```

#### Also...

If you're having a hard time writing plain HTML, you could switch over to some templating language like [Slim](http://slim-lang.com/) or [Haml](http://haml.info/) that will likely error out on invalid code or produce results so unexpected that the error will be obvious. However, knowing the underlying language (HTML) helps build markup with confidence. On top of that, geez, it's a whole extra language! Here's how you partial looks in Slim:

```
.comment_wrapper
  p.comment_name= comment.name
  p.comment_date= comment.created_at
  p.comment_body= comment.body
```

Consider that, and if it's too much for you, feel free to stay with ERB.

Comment: Sorry about that, I made a typo and overlooked it again and again... 
I bet this happens to the best of us, and I am all but the best of us ;)

Comment: @sjbuysse no problem. I just had a chance to debug a similar case. Don't trust your browser, it may have received something completely different :)